# Flickr group pool photos - how to download all group photos

Tags: php, ruby, api, coldfusion, flickr

Our family has created a Flickr group in honor of a recently deceased relative. We are planning to show the group pool slideshow at her memorial service.

The flickr slideshow functionality is great, but it does not auto loop. Plus randomizing photos within a large group pool does not seem to be easy.

I'd like to just download all the group photos and run a slideshow locally.

Are there any reliable tools/scripts that allow downloading of all photos from a flickr group (including "all rights reserved" pics)?

Looking for Mac or Windows desktop tools or some sort of server-side script (PHP, Ruby, or ColdFusion preferred)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm... will be looking into [FlickrDown](http://greggman.com/pages/flickrdown.htm) when I'm back on a Windows machine.

Comment: FlickrDown worked like a charm. It downloaded all 262 large photos from our group pool with ease (including "all rights reserved" photos).
I then created a slideshow using the amazing "Cycle" jQuery plugin. This has 2 advantages over the Flickr slideshow: 1.) all photos are now local, so no need for internet connection. 2.) The Cycle plugin is very customizable and allows for auto-looping (Flickr's lack of auto-looping is the main reason for all of this)

Special thanks to Mike Alsup, author of the Cycle plugin!

Comment: btw -- I really wanted a Mac solution. I tried "Photo Grabbr" for Mac and never got it working correctly. After supposedly downloading images, the specified download folder was still empty. Plus it refuses to download "all rights reserved" images (not that it really matters since it didn't download anything at all!)